# Is it Possible to send notification in Android and IOS when other app is opened/Used

Tags: android, ios, cordova

Is it Possible to send notification in Android and IOS when other app is opened/Used ? If so how to achieve it ?

Sample Scenario:User installs a Coupon providing App.
when the User opens a ecommerce app the coupon app sends a notification of the offer available

Comment: the answer is Yes why not

Comment: Meda, In this case i need to Schedule a background task after specific time and Check the activityMagnager in that task ?

Answer (score 0):

No you can't. You will get the push notification when your app closed.